# getting problems in parsing date in SERVLET

Tags: java, mysql, parsing, servlets

I tried to convert string to date but i cant the required format..
this is my code

```
String a = request.getParameter("bdate");
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(yyyy-MM-dd);

Date bdate = simpleDateFormat.parse(a);
System.out.println(bdate);
```

But I am getting Thu Jan 01 00:00:00 PST 1970 while I want to format the date in yyyy-MM-dd

Comment: what value is coming in var 'a' by input parameter "bdate" ??

Comment: Converting string to date, then back again to string. It's redundant unless the format of the 2 strings are different.

Comment: ITS 1970-01-01  .....

Comment: @Eng.Fouad depends on what is done with the date after printing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `SimpleDateFormat#format()`. The formatter needs to be used both while parsing **and** printing the date out. Otherwise the default format `EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy` that comes from `java.util.Date#toString()` gets used.

```
Date bdate = simpleDateFormat.parse(a);
System.out.println(simpleDateFormat.format(bdate));
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to write it in the desired format write:

```
System.out.println(simpleDateFormat.format(bdate));
```

`java.util.Date` **does not** carry format information

Answer (score 1):

use `new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");` but when ever you want to return formated date 
use `simplDateFormat.format(parsedDate)`

Answer (score 0):

> Thu Jan 01 00:00:00 PST 1970

is Unix-Time 0. This most likely means you "a" is empty or ill-formatted.
Check the parameter input; your parsing code is okay.